# Windbg multiple memory windows

Tags: windbg

I have tried to open multiple memory windows but I can't.

I tried to find resolution for this on windbg help and on old version it is possible, however on new version I can't find how to open multiple memory windows. Please help me!

Comment: What version are you attempting this on?

Comment: My version is 1.2210.3001.0. And I've found how to do it. Ctrl+Shift+m

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post the solution in the answer box for others